# Enabled but unselectable menu item

Tags: vb.net

In WinForms application I need some "caption" in dynamically created ContextMenuStrip.
That caption is changable text composed in ContextMenuStrip_Opening event handler.

For that purpose I'm trying to use ToolStripControlHost with label in it, like this:

```
Dim labelItem As ToolStripControlHost = New ToolStripControlHost(New Label)
...
labelItem.BackColor = Color.Transparent
labelItem.ForeColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.HotTrack)
labelItem.ToolTipText = "mytooltiptext"
mycontextmenu.Items.Add(labelItem)
```

That work almost OK, but...

I try to disable that "labelItem" to avoid clicks and keypresses and then  it becomes gray automatically what is unwanted and also then tooltiptext is not showed.
If "labelItem" is enabled then color is OK, item cannot be selected with keys but can be with mouse and on mouse click it takes focus to itself. That is also unwanted but shows tooltiptext.

Is here a way in described situation to get "labelItem" to be enabled and able to show tooltiptext but be unselectable? In short... How to make an item like is described which would be in color (enabled) but would not accept mouse clicks and take a focus?

Comment: It sounds like you want `CueText`

Answer (score 0):

Don't disable the item.  Set the disabled state image and then in the click event handler, just ignore the case for the item you don't want to be active.

Answer (score 0):

`Enabled` and `Disabled` are predetermined definitions for for the appearance and behavior of a control. `Disabled` will *always* mean the control can't be clicked.

If you need alternate behavior, you'll need to write it yourself. I would suggest tracking two global variables in your form: whether or not your item should be active in a boolean and which object currently has focus in an object. Then use these to write your click event behavior. For example:

```
Public Class Form1
    Public RunEvent As Boolean
    Public HasFocus As Object

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        If RunEvent Then
            'Do something
        Else
            HasFocus.Focus()
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```